# Publish/Deploy Visual Basic 2010 project (.exe file for other PCs)

Tags: vb.net

Hello I have developed a simple application that uses an Access database. In my application my provider and datafile paths for the DB are

```
Dim provider As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source ="
Dim dataFile As String = "C:\Users\blanca\Desktop\Serna Impresos 2016\Serna Impresos 2016\Serna Impresos 2016\bin\Debug\SIDB.accdb"
Dim connString As String = provider & dataFile
```

I know that whenever I download the installation files on another computer it will not work because I used explicit path definition [C:.....\file.accdb] which refers to my own local files. 
How do I use a working directory path? What path should I use for it to work on different computers (not the one used to develop)

The error message is this...
[clic for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0750X.jpg)

Changed this and still doesn't work

```
Dim provider As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source ="
Dim dataFile As String = "\SIDB.accdb"
Dim startup As String = Application.StartupPath
Dim connString As String = provider & startup & dataFile
```

Comment: `Environment.GetFolderPath` provides access to all the User folder names.

Comment: Example? How do I used this command (I am new to VB.net)

Comment: Check my answer,  i'm explaining thd getfolderpath for you

Comment: Where is your anwer? Thanks @Rootel

Comment: The admins deleted all of my answers or edited it.

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't want your database in your application directory.  Users with lower-level privileges will not be able to gain write access to it, and you will pull your hair out trying to figure out why different users end up with different data until you understand that some versions of Windows have a "trick" that creates separate copies of files for each user when you don't have admin privileges.

First determine if the database is supposed to be the same for all users, or if each user should have their own copy.

If they should have their own copy, the AppData folder

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
```

is where you'd want to put the database.

If they should all be working off of a single copy, then you need to make the path an application setting, and make it part of the setup process to stage the database and locate that path.